# Lex is recognizing [ as part of a string of letters instead of a character

Tags: yacc, lex

I'm writing a simple yacc program which checks syntax. I should be able to do something along the lines of

```
int a[100];
```

I have lots of print statements in my program so you can see what's happening. Instead of saying

```
INT found
VAR NAME found
CHAR found
NUMBER found
CHAR found
CHAR found
```

it's saying

```
INT found
VAR NAME found
VAR NAME found
syntax error
```

In my YACC file, I have

```
type VARNAME '[' NUM ']' ';'
```

int my lex file I have

```
[=\-+*/%&|\[\]();{}<>!]     { //return the symbols
                fprintf(stderr,"CHAR found\n");
                            return (*yytext);
            }
[a-zA-z][a-zA-Z0-9]*        { //ID can start with any letter and end with letters and numbers.
                fprintf(stderr,"VAR NAME found\n");
                            yylval.string=strdup(yytext); 
                return(ID);
            }
```

which is the only code relevant to this issue. There are no inconsistencies with the CFG from what I can see, so I'm not sure what the issue is.

Answer (score 2):

I completely agree with [EJP's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28715046/1566221) that you replace that long list of special characters with a simple fallback rule at the end of your scanner definition. But that's not the cause of your problem.

The cause is a simple typo: your pattern for the first character of an `ID` is `[a-zA-z]`, instead of `[a-zA-Z]`. The former pattern matches the characters between <kbd>Z</kbd> and <kbd>a</kbd>, which include <kbd>[</kbd> and <kbd>]</kbd>. So, `[100]` is an `ID` according to your specification.

Personally, I suggest using the Posix character classes, writing:

```
[[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]*
```

or, if you want to include <kbd>_</kbd> (which is also between <kbd>Z</kbd> and <kbd>a</kbd>, as it happens):

```
[[:alpha:]_][[:alnum:]_]*
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you've posted isn't complete. There is nothing there that recognizes the keyword `int,`and you don't have a rule that recognizes numeric literals.

You're over-specifying. Get rid of the first rule, and put a catch-all rule *after* the identifier rule:

```
. return yytext[0];
```

That way:

1. Any legal single-character special characters are handled automatically.
2. Any *illegal* single-character special characters are treated as syntax errors by the parser, which has error recovery.